# Ionic Push notification(Background fone)

Tags: javascript, android, ionic2, onesignal

Hi guys I have ionic application.Where users can send each other messages.It works fine but I want to create push notification for Background fone.

I inistigated Onesignal but it hardly for  using.
And I read that I need keep all users list on them server(https://onesignal.com/).
I have server and backend created by nodeJs.

Could you suggest me other approach.

Thanks Hakob

Answer (score 0):

There are various plugins for push notifications. You need to install them locally on the app and use them as the clients to register to the server and keep receiving notifications.

You can refer [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) or [cordova](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) documentations for the details as it is not apt to mention all the details here.

Brief steps-

1. First you need to configure the server for ex - [Firebase Cloud Messenging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/).
2. Install the plugin and deal with the notifications actions(onregister, onreceive, etc.) in the code.
3. Next, use the server authorization keys got from Step-1 in the plugin code on the app.

Hope this helps.